# Angular 7 Routing and Navigation is not working in IE 11

Tags: navigation, angular7, internet-explorer-11, router, angular7-router

In my Angular application, i have implemented routing using RouterModule. I have three buttons on a page on click of that page gets navigated to another page. Everything is working fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari but it is not working in IE 11.

app.module.ts

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'world', component: WorldComponent },
  { path: 'india', component: IndiaComponent },
  { path:'state', component: StateComponent},
  { path: '**', component: IndiaComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
...
```

app.component.html

```
<nav>
    <button mat-raised-button class="mat-button">
      <a routerLink="/india" routerLinkActive="active">India's Dashboard</a>
    </button>
    <button mat-raised-button class="mat-button">
      <a routerLink="/state" routerLinkActive="active">Indian-State's Dashboard</a>
    </button>
    <button mat-button class="mat-button">
      <a routerLink="/world" routerLinkActive="active">World's Dashboard</a>
    </button>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, if the `<a>` tag located inside the `button` elements. Once we click the button in IE browser, it will trigger the button click event, instead of the `<a>` tag click event. So, the routing not working.

To solve this issue, you could try to use the following methods:

Method 1: Change the `<button>` tag to `<div>` tag.

```
  <div mat-raised-button class="mat-button">
    <a routerLink="/user" routerLinkActive="active">User Dashboard</a>
  </div>
  <div mat-raised-button class="mat-button">
    <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About Dashboard</a>
  </div>
```

Method 2: Put the `<button>` tag in the `<a>` tag.

```
    <a routerLink="/user" routerLinkActive="active"><button mat-raised-button class="mat-button">User Dashboard</button></a>

    <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active"> <button mat-raised-button class="mat-button">About Dashboard</button></a>
```

Method 3: when click the button, use Jquery to trigger the hyperlink click event.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me :)